Skip Lazy Loading by Image Class Added to Figure Element in WordPress
This is how images are output in WordPress:
<figure class="no-lazy"><img loading="lazy" class="wp-image-12345" src="apple.jpg" alt="apple"></figure>

I want to adjust the loading attribute for images in WordPress. I am currently using the following solution using str_replace:
add_action( 'template_redirect', function(){
    ob_start( function( $buffer ){

$buffer = str_replace( array( '<figure class="no-lazy"><img loading="lazy"', "<figure class='no-lazy'><img loading='lazy'"), '<figure class="no-lazy"><img loading="eager"', $buffer );

        return $buffer;
    });
});

However, I believe there is a better way to achieve my goal using wp_img_tag_add_loading_attr.
The wp_img_tag_add_loading_attr solution only works if the class is assigned directly to the image element (img) as follows:
<img loading="lazy" class="no-lazy" src="apple.jpg" alt="apple">

Here's the wp_img_tag_add_loading_attr code that changes the loading attribute of images with class="no-lazy" from lazy to eager:
add_filter( 'wp_img_tag_add_loading_attr', 'skip_lazy_load', 10, 3 );

function skip_lazy_load( $value, $image, $context ) {
    if ( strpos( $image, 'no-lazy' ) !== false ) $value = 'eager';

    return $value;
}

The issue in WordPress is that the class is added to the figure and not the image as follows:
<figure class="no-lazy"><img loading="lazy" src="apple.jpg" alt="apple"></figure>

How do I use preg_match and wp_img_tag_add_loading_attr to achieve the same thing as the str_replace solution above?
'/<figure [^£]*?my_css_class[^£]*?<\/figure>/'

PS - I am not familiar at all with preg_match and I am aware that wp_img_tag_add_loading_attr has been deprecated.

Your uses of $buffer seems to have come out of nowhere. I thought you were telling us that we only had access to $value, $image, $context.

Apologies. I've added the full code with $buffer.

You've haven't posted your resolving code as a question edit, right?  If you have a resolution, that is to be posted as an answer.  Ideally, you shouldn't be performing string surgery like this.  If you have valid HTML, the most reliable technique is to use a DOM parser (like DomDocument).  Can you [edit] your question to show us a minimal example of the $buffer string?

There's actually two solutions in my question. I was attempting to find a third one using preg_match. Will re-arrange my questions so that it makes more sense...

Please [edit] your question to include realistic sample text returned from wp_img_tag_add_loading_attr() so that there is a [mcve].

I don't understand what you're asking for.

Sorry, I mean: What is a realistic sample HTML text that would be in $buffer?  I want to have a good clear picture of what the input value is.

Understood! I'll make an edit.

Managed to use ChatGPT to formulate a solution...

That might help you, but that doesn't help others.  ChatGPT solutions are currently prohibited here.  Solutions do not belong in the question body.  I am only asking you to show a [mcve] by offering realistic sample data which can be used to validate answers.  Your tasks is how to convert some text into new text, but you haven't yet given use the starting text.  Do you see how your question is incomplete?

Here's the solution:
function add_loading_attr_to_img_in_figure($content) {
    // Define the pattern to match a <figure> with the specific class
    $pattern = '/(<figure[^>]*class="[^"]*eager-load[^"]*"[^>]*>)(.*?)(<img[^>]+>)(.*?<\/figure>)/is';

    // Define the replacement to add the loading="eager" attribute to the <img> tag
    $replacement = '$1$2<img loading="eager"$3$4';

    // Use preg_replace to modify the content
    $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);

    return $content;
}

// Add the filter for the_content to modify images in post content
add_filter('the_content', 'add_loading_attr_to_img_in_figure');

